# What does 'requires grad' do in PyTorch and should I use it?

Tags: pytorch

I have a network where I need to add my own parameter that I want to be trainable. I am using [nn.Parameter()](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) to add this but there's a 'Requires Grad' argument and I can't really make sense as to whether I want this to be true or false from reading the documentation. It makes sense that I would set this to be true, because I want this parameter to be optimised as part of the learning process -- but the need for this argument confuses me: if False means it is not optimised as part of the training process, then why would you use nn.Parameter() rather than just using a normal Tensor?

From the documentation I see that it adds the parameter to the list of utterable parameters that you obtain from the model, but I don't see why you would want this if you're not optimising it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, sometimes you might need to freeze/unfreeze some part of your neural network and avoid/let some of the parameters to be optimized during the training. "requires_grad" argument provides an easy way to include or exclude your network's parameters in the backpropagation phase. You just set it to True or False and it's done.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense (not sure of an instance when you would want to do that, but in theory it makes sense). I guess I need to set mine to True so they are optimised.

Comment: Let's say you want to train a GAN in this specific manner: you first train the generator with the discriminator freezed, then you train the discriminator with the generator freezed. And you switch between these modes while you do the training. This would be an example that you do this in real-world.